# Use items in two dimensional array to add records to a table

Tags: vb.net

The table has records already. All I am trying to do is append records to the table. I have a number of floors in a table named FLOORS. I am trying to insert additional floors to the table. In a field on the form the number of tables are entered. If the number entered on the form is > the Table.Count, the additional records are generated and added to the table. Exception message - "Update Failed"

```
 Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
      Try
           Dim FirstCharacter As String
           Dim LastCharacter As String
           Dim ExtraFloors As Integer

           Floor = Me.FloorDbDataSet.Tables("Floor").Rows.Count + 1
           If Floor <= CInt(TxtNoOfFloors.Text) Then
                ExtraFloors = (CInt(TxtNoOfFloors.Text) - Floor)
                MsgBox("Extra Floors - " & ExtraFloors)
           End If
           Floor = Floor + 1
           MsgBox("First floor to be added - " & Floor)
           'setup array
           Dim FloorDetail(ExtraFloors - 1, 1) As String '(row,col)
           For intRow As Integer = 0 To ExtraFloors - 1
                If Floor < 10 Then
                     strFloorNo = "0" & Floor
                Else
                     strFloorNo = Floor
                End If

                FirstCharacter = strFloorNo(0)
                LastCharacter = strFloorNo(strFloorNo.Length - 1)
                If LastCharacter = "1" Then
                     strDescription = FirstCharacter & "1st Floor"
                ElseIf LastCharacter = "2" Then
                     strDescription = FirstCharacter & "2nd Floor"
                ElseIf LastCharacter = "3" Then
                     strDescription = FirstCharacter & "3rd Floor"
                Else
                     strDescription = strFloorNo & "th Floor"
                End If
                FloorDetail(intRow, 0) = strFloorNo
                FloorDetail(intRow, 1) = strDescription
                MsgBox(strDescription & " ==> " & strFloorNo)
                Floor = Floor + 1
           Next intRow

           Dim NewFloorRow As DataRow = FloorDbDataSet.Floor.NewFloorRow
           For outerIndex As Integer = 0 To ExtraFloors - 1
                NewFloorRow("FloorNo") = FloorDetail(outerIndex, 0)
                NewFloorRow("Description") = FloorDetail(outerIndex, 1)
                FloorDbDataSet.Floor.Rows.Add(NewFloorRow)
           Next
           Me.FloorTableAdapter.Update(FloorDbDataSet.Floor)
           FloorTableAdapter.Fill(FloorDbDataSet.Floor)
           FloorBindingSource.MoveLast()
      Catch ex As Exception
           MsgBox(strDescription & " ==> Update failed")
      End Try
 End Sub
```

Comment: Push F8 to debug.

Comment: "Update Failed" is **not** an exception message - its the message your code displays for any and all exceptions.  Get rid of the Try/Catch to see the real problem.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but your way of generating the strDescription is going to produce a 11st Floor, 12nd Floor and 13rd Floor.  It will also not work for more than 99 floors.

Answer (score 0):

Plutonix is absolutely right about your error handling.

However, the original issue is:

Dim NewFloorRow As DataRow = FloorDbDataSet.Floor.NewFloorRow

This should be INSIDE the loop.  Otherwise, your code is trying to add the same row repeatedly, which will cause the error.

```
       For outerIndex As Integer = 0 To ExtraFloors - 1
            Dim NewFloorRow As DataRow = FloorDbDataSet.Floor.NewFloorRow
            NewFloorRow("FloorNo") = FloorDetail(outerIndex, 0)
            NewFloorRow("Description") = FloorDetail(outerIndex, 1)
            FloorDbDataSet.Floor.Rows.Add(NewFloorRow)
       Next
```

And a recommended change to the exception handling:

```
MsgBox(strDescription & " ==> Update failed" & Environment.NewLine & ex.Message)
```

ex.Message is the actual error message.  The exception has other properties too like stacktrace that in certain modes will give you the line number of the error.

Comment: Grateful for help.

Comment: Thanks to Jacob for his input. Greatly appreciated.